# Rails 3: How To Keep Track of My API Usage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

My app as an API which I have no control of. I don't know which users use it, how many times, etc.

What's the best way of doing an analytics system to keep track of my API usage? Does it need to be a Rack app to filter traffic or there's a better solution for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create an interface by your self. All you have to do is, trace users by their request to your app and can track records by identifying them by their api key. So a user request to your api will be their usage and so on.

Comment: Thanks. When you say "trace users", where exactly is that done? At what level can I do that? thanks

Comment: @donald I am assuming that you have registered users who are using your api and had generated unique api key for them. Now when they send a request to your app after serving call a method that recognise that user by their api key and add the information into your model say: History or Usage, and there you can actually put whole information of a user like their id which references to User model, serving time, purpose and a counter to count their usage and many more things you wants to put in. Make sure you call this action/ method before exiting the request call of your user.

Comment: it makes sense thanks. However, is that a scalable solution? Isn't that going to decrease the speed of my API responses? If I have millions of API requests and I still have to do that, it will be bad for my server. If I do a Rack app, can't I analyze that outside my API instance? (Just an idea to solve that possible problem)

Comment: @donald yes it will decease the speed of your API response, so what you can do is just add a column called counter in users table and find user by their api key and update the counter while your app will be serving to user.

Comment: thanks again for the response. One more question. I assume you know getexception and hoptoad. How do they do it? They simply control everything without me having to add anything to the code. What do they use?